# udash tutorial fails to run

Tags: scala, udash

I follow the tutorial on https://guide.udash.io/
but it fails to run:

```
$ sbt new UdashFramework/udash.g8
name [My Udash Application]: 
package [io.company.app]: 
scala_version [2.12.8]: 
udash_version [0.8.0-RC8]: 
sbt_version [1.2.8]: 

$ cd my-udash-application

$ sbt compile compileStatics run
[error] (run-main-1) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.company.app.backend.Launcher
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The launcher `io.company.app.backend.Launcher` with main method is in the project `backend` so try running it like so

```
sbt
project backend
run
```